# filter by multiple columns in BASH

Tags: bash

I would like to filter one csv file without using grep or awk. In one variable I need the counter and in the other I need the sum of three columns.

I've develop a script like this, but is not working. It seems that I can't filter using if conditions. Is there another way to filter columns without using grep neither awk?

```
#!/bin/bash

file=athletes.csv
((c=0))
((sum=0))
for line in $(cat ${file})
do
read  id name nat sex date heigh weight sport gold silver bronze <<<${line}
if (( nat == "$1" )) && (( sport == "$2" ))
then
((c++)) #Participants
((sum+=gold+silver+bronze)) #Medals
fi
done
echo "Count:$c, Sum:$sum"
```

Comment: what values are in the `gold`, `silver`, and `bronze` columns in your csv?

Comment: I suggest you use something like `csvkit` for this. It has numerous utilities to work with csv files from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you [should not read files like that](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), you could instead use a `while read` loop like:

```
while IFS=, read -r id name nat sex date heigh weight sport gold silver bronze; do
  ...
done < "$file"
```

Next you are using arithmetic expansion to compare what I'm assuming are strings which will not work, instead of `(( nat == "$1" ))` for example you probably want `[[ $nat == "$1" ]]`

Assuming your input file just contains only integer values in the gold, silver, and bronze columns you could use this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=input.csv
c=0
sum=0

while IFS=, read -r id name nat sex date heigh weight sport gold silver bronze; do
    if [[ $nat == "$1" && $sport == "$2" ]]; then
        ((c++))
        ((sum+=gold+silver+bronze))
    fi
done < "$file"

printf 'Count: %d, Sum: %d\n' "$c" "$sum"
```